# Calculating future dates in SQL depending on when a list of accounts will each be 90 days past due

Tags: sql, dateadd

I have a list of accounts that are at least 60 days past due but less than 90 days past due as of the end of the prior month (fieldname = procdate). I need to know the date each account will become 90 days past due assuming no payments are made in the future.

Assume I only have two accounts and that procdate is 2017-07-31. One account is 61 days past due.  The other is 70 days past due. What is the date that each will become 90 days past due?

Thus, what is the calculation I can put in my select list to calculate the date each account becomes 90 days past due?

Comment: you should show some sample data and the expected result. also tag the database being used.

Comment: how is it that you know to tag this as "dateadd" but you can't do a websearch to find out how to call the dateadd function?

Comment: Sorry VKP & Hogan don't use DATEADD much and I know it's fairly basic question, but you questions were 'motivating.'  Please see my answer & thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than get hung up on calculating 90 - x (x being past due days or PDDAYS) and then using it with procdate (the end of last month) and DATEADD... I realized I could simply use each loan's original due date (orgduedate) and make the DATEADD far more simple:
DATEADD(dd, 90, orgduedate) as PDDAY90 = the date each loan will be 90 days past due.
Also since I've put the following in the where clause:
PDDAYS >= 60 and PDDAYS < 90
I'm assured that my initial population of loans meets the criteria of the LOB requesting the info.